# php: str_replace or preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

i'm trying to create a script that transform all the relative paths to absolute paths

so how can I find and replace in a html text all the occurences of

```
src="/jsfile.js
```

with

```
src="http://mysite.com/jsfile.js
```

then

```
src="../jsfile.js
```

with

```
src="http://mysite.com/jsfile.js
```

and then

```
src="js/jsfile.js
```

with

```
src="http://mysite.com/js/jsfile.js
```

and maybe more cases? well of course also the href scenarios

### UPDATE

maybe my question was bad written, but the goal is to replace any relative url or relative link to an absolute url... i'm not sure if the answers below are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a single regex using `preg_replace`? It will also work for `href` and `src` attributes. Be sure to check the demo to see it in action!

This converts all of the above test cases correctly:

```
$result = preg_replace( '/(src|href)="(?:\.\.\/|\/)?([^"]+)"/i', '$1="' . $url . '/$2"', $test);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WIHcmX)

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a good comparison.  Those two functions serve separate purposes.  I would personally use three, in this order:

1. preg_match: Find the URLs that need to be modified.
2. substr: Modify the URLs.
3. str_replace: Replace the old URLs with the modified URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If it becomes more than 3, use

```
$pathes=array(
  'src="/jsfile.js' => 'src="http://mysite.com/jsfile.js',
  'src="../jsfile.js' => 'src="http://mysite.com/jsfile.js',
  'src="js/jsfile.js' => 'src="http://mysite.com/js/jsfile.js'
);


$newhtml=str_replace(array_keys($pathes),$pathes,$oldhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('index.html');
$html = preg_replace_callback('#"(\S+).js"#', "replace_url", $html);
function replace_url($url) {
return '"http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].chr(47).trim($url[1], '/,.').'.js"';
}
echo $html;
```

Use preg_replace_callback

Comment: This has some problems: 1. The `.` in the regex will match any character, it should be escaped (`\.`). 2. It will convert invalid strings, such as `"node#js"` to `"http://mysite.com/node.js"`. 3. The performance of `preg_replace_callback` is slower than a single `preg_replace` as there is overhead required to execute the callback function repeatedly.